# Google Earth Engine: batch image export with JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, batch

My goal is to export a large mosaic into tiles defined by individual features in a vector grid (`FeatureCollection`).

[GEE debugging guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/debugging#server-side-errors) states that

> Export is a client-side function and won't work in mapped functions.

But when I use client-side loop the whole thing freezes for a long time due a to multiple `.getInfo()` requests:

```
// vector_grid is a FeatureCollection with 'tile_id' attribute

var tile_list = vector_grid.getInfo()["tile_id"];

for (var i in tile_list) {
  var tile = ee.Feature(tile_list[i]);
  var tile_id = feat.get("tile_id").getInfo().toString();
  var tile_geom = tile.geometry();
  
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: mosaic,
    folder: 'export_path',
    fileNamePrefix: tile_id,
    region: tile_geom,
  });
}
```

The question is:

Is it possible to do a batch export defined by `FeatureCollection` in a more rational way within the JavaScript API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get some information from the tiles to parse to the `Export` function, you will need `getInfo`. Alternatively, you could make some "fake" id in the client side (like using `i` directly).

I think you could get rid of 1 `getInfo`, I've been doing this in the Python API, and haven't test it in JS, so the following code has not been tested, but you can try it:

```js
var tile_list = vector_grid.toList(vector_grid.size())

var i = 0;
while (i < 1e13) {
  try {
    var tile = ee.Feature(tile_list.get(i));
    var tile_id = tile.get("tile_id").getInfo().toString();
    var tile_geom = tile.geometry();

    Export.image.toDrive({
      image: mosaic,
      folder: 'export_path',
      fileNamePrefix: tile_id,
      region: tile_geom,
    });

    i++  
  } catch (err) {
    break;
  }
}
```

***Note***: for the pythonistas, I use `while True:`, but I couldn't find an equivalent in JS